# Dell active pen (PN556W) not pairing

Tags: bluetooth, dell, 20.04, stylus

I see the pen in the list of devices in the bluetooth settings, but I can't pair it. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Latitude 3390.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the steps here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/wacom-stylus.html.en

I don't have a stylus, so I can't test.  But the steps listed in that link may help.

Edit: After the discussion below, I found this documentation: https://www.dellemc.com/resources/en-us/asset/brochures/products/electronics-accessories/Dell_Pen_Compatibility_Brochure.pdf

which suggests that perhaps the Wacom settings could indeed be the ones to try.  Depending on the model of the Dell Active pen, it may be using Wacom protocol to communicate with the screen.

Comment: I have both a Dell pen and a real Wacom Intuos graphics tablet.  I tested both and posted my answer.  I believe those instructions and settings only apply to Wacom external USB graphics tablets, not the Dell pen.

Comment: I believe you are correct, sorry for my confusion.  That being the case, I'm not sure what the solution might be.

Comment: Although, according to Dell's documentation, the touch screen is using Wacom protocol: https://www.dellemc.com/resources/en-us/asset/brochures/products/electronics-accessories/Dell_Pen_Compatibility_Brochure.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have the Dell PN557W and a Dell 5290 2-in-1 tablet with Ubuntu 20.04.  I also have an old Wacom Intuos 4.  Basically everything works but I cant configure any settings for the PN557W and I cant use the button on the end. I will share my experience for reference.

What I found is this:

- Yes the PN557W works smoothly out of the box as a stylus with pressure sensitivity, whether paired or not.
- The PN557W pen shows up in bluetooth devices but like you I cannot pair it.  I think this is only for the bluetooth button functionality but could be wrong.
- With the Wacom Intuos 4, I can plug it in and then move it around on the USB pad and it then it detects in Ubuntu settings and all buttons for it work flawlessly. It shows up like this:
  [image]
- From what I can see, these [Wacom settings](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/wacom.html.en) built into Ubuntu are only for Wacom external USB graphics tablets such as the Intuos.  The settings in Ubuntu only apply to that, and only detect these devices.